# Add notes (for mods to see) to flagged comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderation, flags

Can we get the ability to add a note/message to flagged comments? When I say note/message, I mean a message that is visible only to the admin/moderator who comes across your flag. Not to the community as a whole.

Comment: If you need to *explain why* the comment should be deleted, it probably doesn't need to be.

Comment: @balpha: Not to mention that if it needed to be deleted, surely 4 other people would agree with you and flag it off the page, right?

Comment: @balpha ??? should not a mod always _be able_ to explain why something should be deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as it can be optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can just report the post to the mods with a description of the issue with the comment at fault right now.

I don't think the comment voting/flagging was ever meant to actually matter or be looked at. I certainly don't believe there are enough cases where this would be needed where we would need to add all this complexity to such a simple system.

Answer (score 1):

Why?

Right now, flags are simple - flag a comment enough times, and it goes away.

---

#### Edit:

OK, so you are talking about something similar to the *Flag for moderator review feature* for posts... That still seems like over-kill. 'Time was, we could just delete comments. Any comments. For any reason. Anywhere. Anyone's. And Life Was Good, albeit confusing and full of bizarre arguments half-deleted. Now it feels like they're becoming less annotations and more like a mini-forum attached to each post. If that's the idea, then I'd still rather have threading.

Comment: Notes for the admin who will see your flag. Not notes for others.

Comment: Do moderators get to see which comments are flagged?

Comment: I like the assumption that moderators are watching the comment flags...

Comment: I would hope so.

Comment: @Rich It's a perfectly valid assumption. That's the way moderation generally works. You flag something, and the appropriate authorities come across it. Your sarcasm really is tiresome.

Comment: @Jonathon: Apparently community moderation is a topic that is foreign to you then. Mods aren't deleting the comments, the community is. Your lack of comprehension of what the rest of the community is telling you really is tiresome.

Answer (score 1):

I like it.  Also, a derivative of this would be super-useful.  As far as I can tell, flagged comments don't give any indication the **comment** is flagged as opposed to the **question**.  So Mods needs to go to the question and start hunting.

Of course we review the question in general after a flag, but this would let us zero in immediately.